# Removing rows from one dataset if it matches data in another dataset

Tags: r

I have one data frame with 332 names and another with 56000. All of the 332 names are included in the larger data frame. How do I remove rows of data from the large data frame if the names are included in the smaller data frame?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can your post a minimal reproducible example? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: We're going to need what data structure they're stored in (vector, data frame, data table, tibble etc.). You can find this out with the `class()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Using the built in mtcars dataset in place of your large dataset, use the `%in%` operator to subset to those in a reference data frame (your smaller one) and `!` to make it "not in". Change dataframe names and variables to suit your need.

```
# SETUP
refDF <- data.frame("ID" = c(4,6))
# SOLUTION 
mtcars[!mtcars$cyl %in% refDF$ID,]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
   filter(!cyl %in% refDF$ID)
```

#### data

```
refDF <- data.frame("ID" = c(4,6))
```